# Java/Swing Box Layout with Separator

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, separator, boxlayout

Here is the code:

```
Box twoPanelBox= new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
twoPanelBox.add(panelA); // red
twoPanelBox.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) );
twoPanelBox.add(panelB); // black
```

And here is what i get:

[image: screenshot of panels]

The red and the black panel are displayed as expected, where the seperater ( green box around) has something like a margin between.

How can a avoid this marging, and eliminate this space (grey area)?
Thank you

Comment: What L&F are you using? Try to put `setContentMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0))`

Comment: well this is the correct output, (but for other answerers to) for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with two JPanels and one JSeparator

Comment: @nachokk: I'm using W7 standard [UIManager.setLookAndFeel(     UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little unexpectedly, BoxLayout will stretch the separator. However, this dirty hack will help:

```
JSeparator separator = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
separator.setMaximumSize( new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1) );
mergeBox.add(separator);
```

Comment: not dirty hack, BoxLayout accepting Min/Max and PreferredSize, JSeparator returns own PreferredSize, but there are another two ways